# VF remote object paganition

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

If I am using VF remote objects and I want to allow paging through the results I need to add an `OFFSET` flag.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_remote_objects.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_remote_objects.htm|SkinName=webhelp

I believe I am reading that correctly. Does anyone have any example on how to actually do this? I am not sure where or how to add the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Contact();
ct.retrieve( 
    { where: { 
        FirstName: {eq: 'Marc'}, 
        LastName: {eq: 'Benioff'} 
      }, 
      orderby: [ {LastName: 'ASC'}, {FirstName: 'ASC'} ]
      limit: 1,
      offset: 20},  
    function(err, records) { 
        if (err) { 
            alert(err); 
        } else { 
            console.log(records.length); 
            console.log(records[0]); 
        } 
    } 
);
```

It just gets added with the rest of the conditions.